# python: for-loop doesn't differentiate actions

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I have a list of lists `prova`.
Each list has several elements (dictionary, string, list).

In particular I have a dictionary that is like this:

```
wordDict={'sky':0, 'blue':0,'water':0,...}
```

with all the words that are inside a document of reviews.

I want a `wordDict` populated for each review, I tried in this way:

```
for i in range(len(prova)):
  for word in prova[i][4]:
    prova[i][1][word] += 1
```

`prova[i][4]`: is the place where there is the list with all the word of the review;

`prova[i][1]`: is the place where there is the dictionary, `wordDict`.

The result is that it populates each `wordDict`, but with all the words of all the different reviews, so I have all the lists with same `wordDict`s.

Instead of this, I want each `wordDic`t, for each review, populated just by that review's word, so different from each other.

Comment: While this looks answerable, try to provide a [mcve].

Comment: How did you initially create the (presumably empty) dictionary(s) and assign them to the list?  It sounds like you might have created one dictionary and assigned a reference to it in each of the lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a dictionary of words:

```
word_dict = {'sky': 0, 'blue': 0, 'water': 0}
```

Given a list of reviews:

```
reviews = [
    "the sky is wet water is blue",
    "ice blue silver sky fades into grey",
    "take a look to the sky just before you die"
]
```

We may split up each review into a list of words:

```
review_words = [r.split(' ') for r in reviews]
```

And count the occurrence of relevant words for each review:

```
review_word_dicts = [{k: r.count(k) for k, v in word_dict.items()}
    for r in review_words]
```

Resulting in:

```
>>> review_word_dicts

[{'sky': 1, 'blue': 1, 'water': 1},
 {'sky': 1, 'blue': 1, 'water': 0},
 {'sky': 1, 'blue': 0, 'water': 0}]
```